# package arabxetex produces only blank pages

Tags: fonts, xetex

I've installed the arabxetex package, but whenever I run `xelatex example.tex` the resulting dvi is blank (i.e., `xdvi example.dvi` displays a blank page). The log file has lines:

```
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Ouhod/B (it might not exist) on i
nput line 15.
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Ouhod/I (it might not exist) on i
nput line 15.
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Ouhod/BI (it might not exist) on 
input line 15.
```

It doesn't matter what font I use, I get the same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Update: sample file (actually one of the examples that came with the arabxetex package):

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{arabxetex} % default options are "novoc" and "fdf2alif", 

% other options are "voc", "fullvoc", "utf", "trans" and "fdf2noalif"
% arabxetex loads bidi.sty and fontspec.sty            

%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Ouhud}
% you can also define \farsifont, \uighurfont, etc if you want
%\usepackage{arabxetex}
\begin{document}
This is some text in
English with Arabic insertion
\textarab{\`arabI}.

This is some text in English with
Arabic insertion \textarab[utf]{عربي}.

This is some text in English with
Arabic insertion
\textarab[voc]{\`arabI}.

\begin{arab} wa-ha_dihi fiqraT"uN
bi-al-\`arabiyaT ma\`a kalimaT
inklIziyaT (\textLR{English}).
\end{arab}

\begin{arab}[utf] وهذه فقرةٌ بالعربيةمع كلمة انكليزية (\textLR{English}).
\end{arab}

\begin{arab}[novoc] وَهَذِهِ فِقرَةٌ
 بِالعَرَبِيَة مَعَ كَلِمَة اِنكلِيزِيَة (\textLR{English}).
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the line `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Ouhud}` it doesn't work. That line was uncommented in the original example file; commenting it out causes the package to complain and use a default font.

Comment: When you should usually get at pdf (or an xdv file if you run with `--no-pdf`).

Comment: Also, please add a [minimal code example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Caramdir: This I did not know. I was following the procedure I learned (less than a week ago, when I first started using LaTeX) of `latex file.tex`, `xdvi file.dvi` to preview, `dvipdf file.dvi` to create PDF if the DVI looks good. I just changed latex to xelatex (after finding out I had to do that on another forum). All these things that aren't in the documentation... The PDF looks good (I had no idea it was even getting created), if I don't define a font but leave it up to the default. I'll have to monkey with it. Thanks!

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it). (btw, I just saw that my first comment is missing “use xelatex” after “When you”. Sorry for that.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! And now that you mention it, your first comment does make more straightforward sense with "use xelatex" in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default XeTeX produces only pdf output. The .dvi you are looking at is probably some old file.

Any font you are using should be in your systems font directory (depends on your system; on Linux you can also put it into `$HOME/.fonts`) and should preferably be in otf or ttf format. Then you have to call it by its name (which can differ from the file name; use your systems font previewer to see what a font is called). Also be sure to use recent versions of XeTeX and `fontspec` (e.g. the ones from TeX Live 2010).

Comment: Well, I don't actually believe this, but I think I've been MIS-SPELLING my font names or something equally moronic, because all of a sudden (after opening up openSUSE's font-installation centre to double-check the fonts are actually there), the thing is now working even with that \newfontfamily line uncommented, no complaints or anything. Don't mind me, I think my brain has gone to sleep!